# Как показать невидимое окно?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

У меня есть окно, которое выполняет какой-то процесс с визуализацией. И мне надо чтобы при запуске приложение оно работало, но не показывалось (то есть чтобы произошло событие `Load`). При этом у пользователя всегда есть возможность его показывать и скрывать. Проблема в том что у меня не получается решить этот вопрос без начального мерцания из-за подобного кода.

```
SomeWindow.Show();
SomeWindow.Hide();
```

Ни в Windows Forms, ни в WPF не вижу решения этой проблемы.

Проблема также в том, что окно показывается в TaskBar, но только когда оно видимое. Поэтому мне не подходят хаки вроде

1. Установки прозрачности окна.
2. Установки нулевой широты, высоты и удаления рамок.
3. Вынос окна за пределы экрана и т.д.

Для чего это надо и почему нельзя всё вынести в какой-нибудь `Task`? Потому что код выполняемый окном зависит от визуализации. Мне нужно чтобы человек мог скрывать и показывать окно когда и сколько угодно, но чтобы его состояние было таким же как будто его не скрывали.

Comment: Ага, приходилось мне решать подобную задачу, сейчас поищу...

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44209222/1548895

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получил [ответ на англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210629/1548895). Этот же код работает для WPF если заменить `FormWindowState` на `WindowState`. Суть в том, что надо сначала чтобы перед "показом" установить (в коде или дизайнере):

```
SomeWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
SomeWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Затем выполнить код

```
SomeWindow.Show();
SomeWindow.Hide();
```

И сразу после этого подготавливаем окно для нормального отображения при последующих вызовах `SomeWindow.Show`:

```
SomeWindow.ShowInTaskbar = true; // Если надо чтобы форма показывалась на панели быстого запуска.
SomeWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; // или FormWindowState.Maximized если надо
```

Это можно превратить в метод расширения для Windows Forms:

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static void ShowInvisible(this Form form)
    {
        // сохраняем параметры окна
        bool needToShowInTaskbar = form.ShowInTaskbar;
        FormWindowState initialWindowState = form.WindowState;

        // делаем окно невидимым
        form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

        // показываем и скрываем окно
        form.Show();
        form.Hide();

        // восстанавливаем параметры окна
        form.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
        form.WindowState = initialWindowState;
    }
}
```

или для WPF:

```
public static class WindowHelper
{
    public static void ShowInvisible(this Window window)
    {
        // сохраняем параметры окна
        bool needToShowInTaskbar = window.ShowInTaskbar;
        WindowState initialWindowState = window.WindowState;

        // делаем окно невидимым 
        window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;

        // показываем и скрываем окно
        window.Show();
        window.Hide();

        // восстанавливаем параметры окна
        window.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
        window.WindowState = initialWindowState;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Просто так вам не получится вызвать событие `Loaded`: оно вызывается лишь тогда, когда ваше окно реально было показано. Но, возможно, у вас сработает обходной путь, который сработал в моём проекте.

Для начала, мы отделим контент окна в `UserControl`. Окно пусть будет пустым. Контрол назовём `SimpleUserControl` для примера.

Теперь мы в начале работы приложения создаём контрол, но не показываем его, таким образом:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var uc = new SimpleUserControl(); // создали контрол
                                          // возможно, надо установить DataContext
        var size = new Size(100, 100);    // фейковый размер
        uc.Measure(size);                 // заставляем пробежать layout engine
        uc.Arrange(new Rect(size));
        uc.UpdateLayout();
        // дождёмся выполнения пустой лямбды на фоновом приоритете,
        // это даст время привязкам разрешиться
        await Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(
            () => { },
            DispatcherPriority.Background);

        // теперь можно работать с контролом. я просто сделаю паузу для примера
        await Task.Delay(9000);

        // и вставить его в окно:
        new MainWindow() { Content = uc }.Show();
    }
}
```

При этом `Loaded` на контроле всё ещё не вызывается (оно вызовется только при показе), но у вас подконтролы будут находиться в «рабочем» состоянии.

Comment: Ого, а есть что-то попроще? А то я напротив хотел более элегантно решить… Но всё равно огромное спасибо за старания.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: У меня, к сожалению, элегантно не получилось :-\ Но у меня было более жёсткое требование: UI вовсе не должен был показываться, никогда.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, при создании формы:

- её не должно быть видно,
- должно сработать событие `Load`,
- её иконка должна появиться на таскбаре,
- форма не не должна мелькнуть.

По-моему, установка прозрачности в ноль перед показом, а после показа в единицу полностью решает проблему.

```
var form = new Form();
form.Opacity = 0;
form.Load += Form_Load;
form.Show();
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
form.Opacity = 1;
```

Событие вызывается, форма не мелькает, на таскбаре отображается.

Comment: На таскбаре должна отображаться только когда видимая. А когда скрыта (также при запуске, то должна отображаться.