# Как загрузить вторую форму в фоновом режиме?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как при открытии приложения, загрузить форму `Form2` в фоновом режиме, при условии, что сначала загружается `FormMain` (основная форма, при открытии приложения)?

При нажатии на `pictureBox` открывается `Form2` внутри `panelMain`, но на ее открытие тратится около двух секунд, т.к. на `Form2` много ресурсов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете реализовать синглтон с вашей формой, но это так себе решение.

Comment: Покажите на время загрузки формы `SplashScreen`

Comment: Что находится на форме Form2 (что занимает эти 2 секунды)?

Comment: На форме Form2 находится куча picureBox

Comment: Приведите **конкретный** пример, что находится на форме и как загружаются ресурсы. Что именно подразумевается под словом "ресурсы"? Контролы WinForms или данные с диска/из БД? Если контролы, то в любом случае инициализироваться они должны при показе формы - с этим сделать ничего **невозможно**. Если проблема в долгой загрузке данных - это элементарно делается в фоновом потоке.

Comment: На форме `Form2` которая отображается в `panel1` много ресурсов, изображений, после первого открытия формы, последующее открытие формы происходит моментально. Изображения в виде прямоугольников, 50х20 штук 40, они расположены внутри `pictureBox`, количество `pictureBox` равно количеству изображений. Если первый раз форма открывается долго, а второй раз быстро, то должен быть способ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я задавался похожим [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671369/220571) и нашёл [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671495/220571). Поэтому рекомендую метод расширения

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static void ShowInvisible(this Form form)
    {
        // сохраняем параметры окна
        bool needToShowInTaskbar = form.ShowInTaskbar;
        FormWindowState initialWindowState = form.WindowState;

        // делаем окно невидимым
        form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

        // показываем и скрываем окно
        form.Show();
        form.Hide();

        // восстанавливаем параметры окна
        form.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
        form.WindowState = initialWindowState;
    }
}
```

Затем в констукторе `MainForm` и при клике на `pictureBox`:

```
public class MainForm
{
    private readonly Form2 _form2 = new Form2();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _form2.ShowInvisible();
    }

    private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только возникли трудности, подскажите, что я делаю не так? [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675392/)

Comment: Все получилось, еще раз спасибо! Теперь переключение между формами отображается быстрее.

Comment: Еще одно решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672149/ (с использованием переменных для форм).

Comment: К сожалению оба решения не совсем решают задачу. Если например, вставить в форме Form2 паузу System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); то приложение будет висеть эти самые 10 секунд :(

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk А вы используйте `Task` и/или `async` в случае необходимости. Не совсем понимаю проблему.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Если у вас что-то специфическое, создайте отдельный вопрос, киньте ссылку на него сюда – я постараюсь ответить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov спасибо, я сделал отдельный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676548/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk чем новый вопрос отличается от этого?

Comment: @PashaPash Ну это действительно разные вопросы. Этот как отобразить невидимую форму, а тот — про асинхронность или многопоточность.

Answer (score 4):

Если "ресурсы" на Form2 не привязаны к отрисовке - вынесите из загрузку из конструктора / `InitializeComponent` в отдельный поток (хотя бы перебросьте их в async `Form2_Load`).

Если ресурсы действительно привязаны к отрисовке, из загрузку вы никак не контролируете, и их инициализацию обязательно выполнять в UI Thread - запускайте еще одни message pump для второй формы.

```
// вызов конструктора на потоке из пула, на случай если в конструкторе попадется что-то медленное
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
    Application.Run(new Form2())
);
```

Форма получит свой собственный UI Thread, так что работать с ней из `Form1` и обратно придется через `Invoke`.

Comment: Еще такой способ, на основе отображения формы до загрузки приложения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672149/

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать вот так

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Task<Form2> _formCreator;
    private Form _form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _formCreator = Task.Run(() => new Form2());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2 = _formCreator.Result;
        _form2.FormClosing += (o, args) =>
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
            (o as Form)?.Hide();
        };
        _form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Чтобы при дальнейшем открытии не создавалось заново, надо при закрытии просто скрывать окно
Если еще не поздно.

Comment: Тогда как загружать все ресурсы вместе с `FormMain`? Чтобы при открытии второй формы они уже были подгружены, и не тратилось время на их загрузку.

Comment: Форма это просто класс, почему нельзя создать экземпляр класса?