# Метод расширения (ошибка)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? (посмотрите изображения ниже)

Для удобства `FormControl` это `Form2` (для понимания вопроса, вот тема: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672644/))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MySoft
{
    public partial class FormControl : Form
    {
        public static class FormHelper
        {
            public static void ShowInvisible(this Form form)
            {
                // сохраняем параметры окна
                bool needToShowInTaskbar = form.ShowInTaskbar;
                WindowState initialWindowState = form.WindowState;

                // делаем окно невидимым
                form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

                // показываем и скрываем окно
                form.Show();
                form.Hide();

                // восстанавливаем параметры окна
                form.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
                form.WindowState = initialWindowState;
            }
        }
        public FormControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Остальной код
    }
}
```

[image: Метод расширения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отдельный класс `FormHelper.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MySoft
{
    public static class FormHelper // У этого класса ноль ссылок...
    {
        public static void ShowInvisible(this FormControl form)
        {
            // сохраняем параметры окна
            bool needToShowInTaskbar = form.ShowInTaskbar;
            FormWindowState initialWindowState = form.WindowState;

            // делаем окно невидимым
            form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

            // показываем и скрываем окно
            form.Show();
            form.Hide();

            // восстанавливаем параметры окна
            form.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
            form.WindowState = initialWindowState;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Дак вам же студия вроде сообщает причину проблемы, что не так?

Comment: Мне трудно разобраться, что именно нужно сделать...

Comment: А вы можете создать класс `FormsHelper` в отдельном файле?

Comment: Создал, но у `public static class FormHelper` нет ссылок... количество `0`

Comment: Это нормально, главное чтобы ссылки были у методов. Класс `FormControl` должен также содержать `namespace`, где лежит класс `FormsHelper`. Если это не получается, то применяйте [ответ Sv__t](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675402/220571).

Comment: Решился вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо за советы, ошибки исчезли, и подгрузка формы таким способом даже выявила ошибку в ссылке на ресурс. Признателен, что не оставили вопрос без внимания. Все получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете использовать такие параметры `(this Form form)` во вложенном классе. Соответственно, нужно вынести класс. И исправьте `WindowState` на `FormWindowState`:

```
namespace MySoft
{ 
     public static class FormHelper
     {
        public static void ShowInvisible(this Form form)
        {
            // сохраняем параметры окна
            bool needToShowInTaskbar = form.ShowInTaskbar;
            FormWindowState initialWindowState = form.WindowState;

            // делаем окно невидимым
            form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

            // показываем и скрываем окно
            form.Show();
            form.Hide();

            // восстанавливаем параметры окна
            form.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
            form.WindowState = initialWindowState;
        }
    }


    public partial class FormControl : Form
    {

        public FormControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Остальной код
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за найденную опечатку, исправил во всех трёх ответах.

Comment: Такой способ делает такую ошибку: `Класс FormControl можно сконструировать, но это не первый класс в файле.  В Visual Studio конструктор должен использовать первый класс в файле.  Переместите код класса, чтобы он был первым в файле, и еще раз попробуйте загрузить конструктор.`

Comment: Если переместить класс в самый низ основного кода, под концовку `public partial class FormControl : Form` то все работает. Спасибо и за этот вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите класс `FormHelper` за пределы класса `FormControl`.
Он не может быть вложенным, о чем вам IDE и говорит.
И в оригинальном ответе это был класс "сам по себе", а вы его внутрь другого засунули.