# Как загрузить вторую форму асинхронно и запустить её при нажатии кнопки пользователем?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Дано: 2 формы.

Главная форма содержит кнопку по которой вызывается второстепенная форма (форма 2).

Форма 2 содержит паузу `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)` для имитации сложной работы (загрузки компонентов, множества изображений, отрисовки).

Задача: мгновенно отобразить форму 2 при нажатии кнопки на главной форме. При этом до нажатия кнопки, пользователь не должен видеть форму 2 (даже мелькающую). Кнопку пользователь нажмет не ранее, чем через 10 секунд после старта программы.

Я перепробовал варианты с запуском в другом потоке, пытался использовать просто `Task`, `BackgroundWorker`, `ThreadPool`. Не получается, как правило проблема при вызове формы по второй кнопке.

Какие есть идея?

Один из примеров, как я пытался решить задачу:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += (s, ea) =>
        {
            frm.Show();
            // В форме 2 стоит this.Visible = false;
        };
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Console.WriteLine("button1_Click");
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(frm.ShowForm));
}

// Form 2:
public void ShowForm()
{
        Console.WriteLine("Form2 showForm");
        this.Visible = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.BringToFront();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всю долгую логику надо засунуть в конструктор второй формы (это я думаю логично). А дальше при запуске первой, в отдельном потоке создать вторую форму. И оставить её в памяти. По клику по кнопке её просто показать. Что то вот в этом роде:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form2 _form;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new Thread(()=>{_form = new Form2();}).Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _form.Show();
        }
    }
```

Единственная проблема данного кода, если пользователь нажмет кнопку ДО того как форма загрузится, все упадет. Но тут можно или просто проверять на Null, или использовать таски и проверять при нажатии кнопки что таска завершилась).

Comment: Я пробовал сделать именно так, при нажатии button1 возникает ошибка обращения из другого потока. Пробовал применить Invoke - все намертво виснет.

Comment: Только что проверил, проблем с работой второго потока нет. Там нет дополнительного кода? Что конкретно вызывает сбой?

Comment: Не взлетит. Формы так просто нельзя использовать в другом потоке.

Comment: Ну значит у меня зрительные галлюцинации) Добавляю проект, чтобы они были не только у меня)
https://yadi.sk/d/nqGN-DPF3JvKb3 
А по поводу потоков, нельзя обращаться к UI формы из другого потока.
Но строить объекты - не вызывает особых проблем.
P.S. Нажимать на кнопку можно только через 5 секунд после старта приложения (я не ставил проверок на построенный объект), 
Иначе будет исключение.

Comment: @Вадим Действительно, все работает, спасибо! Я перемудрил, действительно задача простая.

Comment: Ну значит к врачу мне пока рано)). А вообще... все почему то активно путают саму форму и её "отображение" (UI). Все элементы пользовательского интерфейса действительно должны работать в отдельном потоке и попытка обращения к ним из других потоков вызовет падение (ну если не использовать специальных схем). Проблема в том что сама форма != UI. Это обычный класс. И строить его (и все что внутри) можно так же как любой другой класс. А уже дождавшись когда все остальное отработает, можно из главного потока обращаться к UI (поэтому у меня и Button_Click и form.Show работают в главном потоке)).

Comment: Дело в том, что так можно выполнить только конструктор формы. Но многие действия по инициализации гуевых контролов в нём невозможно закончить: например, установить ширину колонок датагрида после привязки данных. Такие действия нужно выполнять в момент первого показа формы, скажем, в событии Load. И если они длительные, то форма опять-таки мелькает. Но если у автора этого нет, то хорошо.

Comment: Не знаю, если честно я еще ни разу за свою практику не видел длительной работу именно UI. Ширина колонок датагрида должна устанавливаться мгновенно (если у вас с ним тормоза, и вы не используете виртуализацию, то никакая многопоточность не спасет). Длительными обычно бывают операции чтения/записи, какие либо расчеты, формирования. А это все с UI не связано. И да, так можно выполнить не только конструктор. Любые методы на форме не трогающие интерфейс выполняются так же).

Answer (score 6):

## [Не блокируйте поток UI долгими операциями](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Выполняйте их асинхронно.

Поэтому не стоит делать вещи вроде `Thread.Sleep()`. Не в коем случае не стоит в потоке UI вызывать вызывать методы (допустим `SomeMethod(…)`) возвращающие `Task<T>`, просто `SomeMethod(…).Result` – это вызывает deadlock.

Допустим есть метод возвращающий JSON:

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Вот так делать **неправильно**, мы так получим deadlock.

```
private void Button1_Click(...)
{
    var jsonTask = GetJsonAsync(...);
    // Тут мы получаем deadlock
    textBox1.Text = jsonTask.Result;
}
```

Вместо это **правильно** было бы сделать так:

```
public async void Button1_Click(...)
{
    var json = await GetJsonAsync(...);
    textBox1.Text = json;
}
```

#### Вывод

Решаем задачи освобождения потока UI таким образом: добавляем модификатор `async` к обработчику события (это `Load`, `Click` и т.д., в основном они получаются `async void`). Далее внутри него выполняем какой-либо `Task` с помощью `await`.

Поэтому в итоге что-то получается вроде:

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000); // Допустим сделаем ожидание 10 секунд
    var r = await … // Некоторый Task<Result>;
}
```

Comment: +1, но почему «не стоит вызывать вызывать методы возвращающие `Task<T>`»?

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, исправил формулировку.