# Visible = true не отрабатывает

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, из которой вызываю другую форму:

```
progressPanel_Wait.Visible = true;

Form1 F1 = new Form1() 
{ 
    ShowInTaskbar = true 
};

F1.Show();
```

Перед вызовом пытаюсь отобразить контролл. В контроле надпись "Пожалуйста, подождите". Ожидание до отображения формы F1 составляет несколько секунд. Во время ожидания на форме так и не отображается надпись. Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: На каком событии появляется вторая форма?

Comment: Длительные операции нельзя делать в gui-потоке. Пока они не закончатся, gui не прорисуется.

Comment: Вторая форма при нажатии на Button.

Comment: Неужели нельзя отобразить контрол на форме и затем создать экземпляр другой формы?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Конечно можно, но у вас я так понимаю, проблема именно в том, что вы пытаетесь в UI-потоке делать медленные операции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для этого `Task` и `async/await`.
В связи с архитектурой `winforms` это единственный возможный вариант отображения состояния.

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов не можно :)

Comment: @АлександрПузанов вот [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676601/220571), там достаточно понятно старался разжевать.